# Task.Factory.StartNew not working parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I want to find out how `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` works, which can be found here [on the parallel example page.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/04/9990342.aspx). The `ConcurrentPriorityQueue` is in the ParallelExtensionExtras project, under the CoordinationDataStructures folder.

So I wrote a small example that launches a bunch of Tasks which shall insert into the queue in parallel, for two reasons:

1. See whether it is threadsafe
2. See how it performs

But after all, only one core of my laptop seems to be working on that issue.

Here is the code:

```
class Program
{
    public static ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, string> _queue = new ConcurrentPriorityQueue<int, string>();
    public static int _itemCount = 100000;
    public static int _taskCount = 20;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[_taskCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < _taskCount; ++i)
        {
            int prio = i; // possibly a closure problem here?
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EnqueueItems(prio));
            tasks[i] = task;
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        for (int j = 0; j < _taskCount; ++j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( j.ToString() + "  count= " + _queue.Where(x => x.Key.Equals(j)).Count());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void EnqueueItems(int prio)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _itemCount; ++i)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(prio, i.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

So, the insertion works, but it is slow and only one core gets load.

At the moment my only explanation is that the Queue slows down the whole process
that much which would be aweful for a ConcurrentQueue. And, as it is from Microsoft
itself, I do not expect that.

Any problem with my testcode?

It is only slightly changed from [MSDN on waiting for Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: This seems like it might be a more appropriate time to use the [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx). Obviously that doesn't answer your question, but it might provide a workaround that's actually better for what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you, will investigate. TPL Dataflow as a alternative to Task I believe. But the unit under inspection is the ConcurrentPriorityQueue. Which right now does not perform well in this small example.

Comment: `only one core of my laptop seems to be working` how do you know? How do you know which core, more specifically logical core, is the thread running on? `Task Manager` isn't a good source to determine this. The CPU might perform context-switching over 1000 times per second, and Task Manager doesn't exactly keep track of that.

Comment: I watched in process explorer and get a 12,5% cpu usage, no matter how many items I insert or how many threads I use. In other parallel programs I wrote I have at least more than that, most of the time something about 99% cpu usage while computation is running. I know this is not a very good way of measuring, but it gives me a hint that something is wrong here. Here only two things could possibly go wrong: `Task.Factory.StartNew` or the `ConcurrentPriorityQueue.Enqueue`, which both would be very bad... or: something with my code is wrong, which is the reason for this question.

Comment: In your `EnqueueItems()` method, print out the ThreadID using `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` and see if the numbers are different.

Comment: You are right, all different threads. Probably I have to look for a different ConcurrentPriorityQueue then.

Comment: Also, invoking `Task.StartNew()` 20 times doesn't necessarily create 20 different threads. It uses the .NET ThreadPool object, which manages threads based on the environment and application/system load.

Comment: Is that queue capable of executing in parallel? Maybe it just wraps everything in a lock.

Comment: @usr This is what I suspect, too. At least after adding the output of the treadid. Lots of different threads which are started quickly but it still performs poorly

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
Task.Factor.StartNew(..., cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default)
```

LongRunning helps get the task get started in parallel quicker.

Comment: Thank you. The behaviour stays the same.